# Crontab doesn't run Python script on reboot

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I have two python scripts for my app to work.
I want them to start at boot but only one (the gunicorn/mon) script starts.

My Crontab:

```
@reboot /home/daniel/mon/start.sh
@reboot /home/daniel/bot1/start.sh
```

Mon start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -dmS bb-mon /bin/bash -c 'cd /home/daniel/mon && 
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn app:app --bind 0.0.0.0:9999'
```

works.

Bot1 start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -dmS bb-bot /bin/bash -c 'cd /home/daniel/bot1 && 
/usr/bin/python3 app.py'
```

Not working. I tested several outputs in my screen session which appears. The screen session will be started also but the python script does not start.
If I add something like `> log.txt` after the python call the file is empty.
Starting the script without screen doesn't work too.

Answer (score -1):

If your cron is set up correctly, you should get an e-mail when a cronjob fails.

But it could be that the error isn't logged because of the complicated setup where `bash` calls `screen` that calls `bash` to run Python.

Try running Python directly from cron, using an absolute path for the script:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/daniel/bot1/app.py 2>&1 > /var/log/bot1.log
```

I would advise you to capture any output from `app.py` in a logfile, as I've done in the example above.

Comment: If you tested running Python directly, and you don't see *any* output or error, nor a running process, you should probably look into `app.py`. Maybe add some extra debugging `print` calls.